# Inputbox width on body click remove function

Tags: javascript, mootools

I am new with JavaScript and I am trying to use it on my Inputbox.
I know how to add the width when I click on the Inputbox but I don't know how to remove the function on body click.

Check out [this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/r4nEv/).

Answer (score 4):

Use `blur` event on textbox:

```
var box    = $$('.inputbox');    
box.addEvent('blur', function myfunction(event){    
        box.morph({width:210});
});​
```

See Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/r4nEv/1/

Comment: Thank you for your replay. 

I used the blur, but that is not what i need, i need on body click.

Comment: @user1660227 Why specifically the body? What requirements are there which `blur` does not suffice?

Comment: I have search box with results, when i click on the inputbox it goes wider, but now when i click on the results that are underneath, the inputbox goes smaller, that's why i need on body click, so when i click on the results it doesn't go smaller, stays same, unless i click on body.

Answer (score 0):

I would probably add the click event the result and not to the document body as well as use blure to make sure that the box is reset. here is a quick fiddle to demonstrate this.

http://jsfiddle.net/r4nEv/4/

Hope this helps!